# dropdown without value in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, html-select

I try to fill 2 dropdownbox with this code:

```
ViewBag.city = new SelectList(_db.regions.Select(r => r.region_main).Distinct(), "region_main");
ViewBag.region = new SelectList(_db.regions, "region_name", "region_name");
```

and use this code on my view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("region_main", (SelectList)ViewBag.city, "-- انتخاب ---", new { id = "city"})
@Html.DropDownList("region_name", (SelectList)ViewBag.region, "-- انتخاب ---", new { id = "region" })
```

I have problem because first dropdown does not get value.

Comment: There is no constructor of SelectList that takes an IEnumerable and a string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.108).aspx, are you sure you didn't want ViewBag.city = new SelectList(_db.regions.Select(r => r.region_main).Distinct().ToList())?

Comment: this my html output <select id="city" name="region_main"><option value="">-- انتخاب ---</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select> it doest have value for each option

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

`ViewBag.city = new SelectList(_db.regions.Select(r => r.region_main).Distinct().ToList(), "region_main","region_main");`

You have to provide both the name and value field.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: I get this error :DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'region_main'.